# monitor function name error using simpy

Tags: python, simpy

very new to python and trying to use a simpy script I found online to queue times.  I am getting a name error when I use "Monitor" - which I thought was part of SimPy.  Is there somewhere else I should be importing monitor from?

Thanks in advance for the help!

See below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import generators
import simpy

from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from random import Random,expovariate,uniform
# MMC.py simulation of an M/M/c/FCFS/inft/infty queue
# 2004 Dec updated and simplified
#  $Revision: 1.1.1.5 $ $Author: kgmuller $ $Date: 2006/02/02 13:35:45 $

"""Simulation of an M/M/c queue

Jobs arrive at random into a c-server queue with
exponential service-time distribution. Simulate to
determine the average  number and the average time
in the system.

- c = Number of servers = 3
- rate = Arrival rate = 2.0
- stime = mean service time = 1.0

"""
__version__='\nModel: MMC queue'

class Generator(Process):
    """ generates Jobs at random """

def execute(self,maxNumber,rate,stime):
     ##print "%7.4f %s starts"%(now(), self.name)
    for i in range(maxNumber):
        L = Job("Job "+`i`)
        activate(L,L.execute(stime),delay=0)
        yield hold,self,grv.expovariate(rate)

class Job(Process):
    """ Jobs request a gatekeeper and hold it for an exponential time """

    def execute(self,stime):       
        global NoInSystem
        arrTime=now()
        self.trace("Hello World")
        NoInSystem +=1
        m.accum(NoInSystem)
        yield request,self,server
        self.trace("At last    ")
        t = jrv.expovariate(1.0/stime)
        msT.tally(t)
        yield hold,self,t
        yield release,self,server
        NoInSystem -=1
        m.accum(NoInSystem)
        mT.tally(now()-arrTime)
        self.trace("Geronimo   ")

    def trace(self,message):
        if TRACING:
            print "%7.4f %6s %10s (%2d)"%(now(),self.name,message,NoInSystem)



TRACING = 0

print __version__
c = 3
stime = 1.0
rate = 2.0
print "%2d servers, %6.4f arrival rate,%6.4f mean service time"%(c,rate,stime)
grv = Random(333555) #  RV for Source
jrv = Random(777999) #  RV for Job
NoInSystem = 0
m=Monitor()
mT=Monitor()
msT=Monitor()
server=Resource(c,name='Gatekeeper')

initialize()
g = Generator('gen')
activate(g,g.execute(maxNumber=10,rate=rate,stime=stime),delay=0)
simulate(until=3000.0)


print "Average number in the system is %6.4f"%(m.timeAverage(),)
print "Average time in the system is   %6.4f"%(mT.mean(),)
print "Actual average service-time is  %6.4f"%(msT.mean(),)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're more likely to get an answer by posting a **small** working example, and if you can post the actual error message and which line it's coming from, that is also helpful.

Comment: You are using the old and unsupported SimPy 2. Please consider using SimPy 3: simpy.readthedocs.org

Answer (score 0):

You are currently receiving a `name error` because `Monitor` hasn't currently been defined within your script. In order to use the `Monitor` from within `simpy`, you will need to either change `import simpy` to `from simpy import Monitor` or append `simpy.Monitor` for the locations that you are currently using the `Monitor` function.

Ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import generators
from simpy import Monitor
```

Or (lines 71-73):

```
m=simpy.Monitor()
mT=simpy.Monitor()
msT=simpy.Monitor()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When I append simpy.Monitor I now get an attribute error:

module has no object "monitor"

Any ideas?

Comment: @JayFrank Well I don't see `monitor` within your code above, so it is either within one of your dependencies or you have `simpy.monitor` instead of `simpy.Monitor()` somewhere. Without the exact error message it is hard to tell which case it could be.

Comment: Here is the code that gets the error

     **m=Monitor()**

and here is the error when I switch it to 

    **m=simpy.Monitor()**

    **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'monitor'**